# Running a script from a keybinding

Tags: 13.10, shortcut-keys, scripts

I've written two small scripts to change my monitor configurations.  When I run these scripts from the terminal they work perfectly, however I don't seem to be able to get them to work with keybinds.

I'm using Ctrl+Shift+F11 and Ctrl+Shift+F12 for my binds, and if I set one of these for example to run "gnome-terminal" it works as expected.

However, when I try and run one of my scripts, nothing happens.

My script is located in "~/.dotfiles/local/scripts/outputDVI0-1.sh" and this is the exact command I've placed in the command section of the key binding.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Try using `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.dotfiles/...` instead. of the `~/.dotfiles/...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the following command for your custom shortcut:

```
$HOME/.dotfiles/local/scripts/outputDVI0-1.sh
```

See the next answer to understand why:

- [Difference between $HOME and '~' (tilde)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587382/2353900)

Comment: It seems $HOME doesn't work either from the key binding, however if I use /home/USERNAME/.dotfiles/.... it does work

Comment: @Kingamajick `$HOME` should work; for me it does...